# Single Queue and multiple consumers in RabbitMQ

Tags: scala, rabbitmq, amqp, rabbitmq-exchange

I have a single queue in RabbitMQ where there can be 5-6 tasks queued at a time. Currently, there is one worker for the queue which takes one task at a time and until the said task is completed and acknowledged other tasks of the queue won't be picked. I want to have multiple consumers for the same queue. So that they would take the remaining tasks and process them without any idle time.

Answer (score 0):

3 options:

1. Start more threads in the consumer application
2. Start up more instances of the consumer application
3. Consume more than one message at the time and delegate the messages to worker threads.